# Local background image doesn't show up, but if I replace it with one on the web it does work

Tags: html, css, background-image, local

Here is my HTML and CSS
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YBmLJR

```css
header{
    background-image: url(slike\header\header-ozadje.png);
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #E2B654;
}
#top-logo img{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 100%; height: auto;
    padding: 5%;
}
nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    flex: none;
    margin-right: 2%;
}
.nav-text{
    margin: 15px;
    flex: none;
}
.nav-text a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font: bold 16px/28px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: antiquewhite;
}
.nav-text a:hover{
    color: #DFB76B;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <div id="top-logo">
            <img src="slike\logo\astroplanet-logo.png"> 
        </div>      
        <nav>
            <div class="nav-text"><a href="#">DOMOV</a></div>
            <div class="nav-text"><a href="#">DOMOV</a></div>
            <div class="nav-text"><a href="#">DOMOV</a></div>
            <div class="nav-text"><a href="#">DOMOV</a></div>
            <div class="nav-text"><a href="#">DOMOV</a></div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

The background image linking to my local folder (I copied the relative path in VSC, so it should be correct) in my header doesn't show up, but it does if I replace it with a URL that is on the web.

If you run the code there is also the logo, but that should have the broken link image.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: it means image path is incorrect

Comment: But I copied it from VSC? It must be correct, no?

Comment: .check the network tab it will show you the absolute url of the image then you can see whether it's correct or not

Comment: Thank you!! Didn't even know about network tab. What happened is, that I needed to turn " \ " into " / ".
Is this a CSS thing, because using src in HTML works fine when copying with VSC relative path?

Comment: yes you have to use "/" format not the system path format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before location you have to put slash you should replace your image location with this
        background-image: url(/slike/header/header-ozadje.png);

Answer (score 1):

Try to use relative path like **.\slike\header\header-ozadje.png** or **\slike\header\header-ozadje.png**. The problem is with the path of the image.

Your html file should be in parent directory of slike folder.

If you are using windows use "\" if linux use "/". It should work.

Answer (score 0):

use slash in css url

```
background-image: url(slike/header/header-ozadje.png);
```